# Normalization/ERD for Flight Schedule

Tags: mysql, normalization, erd, 3nf

A user who schedules planes for flights determines the type of plane to be used each day for each flight, and can change the type of plane if necessary. Normalize to 3NF and come up with a relational model. You should look at the data carefully and note details like Flight #'s are not unique, but they appear to determine other attributes.

[image: given table]

How can I normalize this? If there are no unique identifiers (primary keys) then how can this be done? I've started drawing the dependencies(below), but I'm not sure where to go from here/if I'm doing it right.

[image: work so far]

Comment: Even though the final result does not use IDs, that does not mean your base tables should not have int field primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
**Flight**
Flightid, flight_num, plane_typeid, destinationid, departdatetime

**Reservation**
Reservationid, Flightid, seatsreserved, userid

**Destination**
Destinationid, destination

**Plane_type**
Plane_typeid, Plane_type, capacity

**User**
Userid, firstname, lastname
```

Comment: All other values on the final report can be derived from the information in the tables e.g. Depart time and depart date are merely modifications to the query statement.

Comment: Hi @Chris if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Im not supposed to create any additional columns but I can make a composite identifier. So I combined flight_num and date to make the flight_id composite key. So I can still do something similar to what you suggested. Thanks